Stop a user deleting an external database in Azure Synapse Analytics
Is there a way to limit a user to read, write execute but not delete an external database.
we create a role with READ access but when a user assigned to this role Click on delete an external database (Lake database) he can delete the database. Is there any way to protect the external database from being deleted from users with Read only access.

Have you tested this actually deletes something or just gives the option? What other permissions does the user have in the workspace and or resource group?
